# How to open a doc file in browser without prompting a dialog box?

Tags: php

I want to open a doc file in browser without prompting a dialog box.
Whenever click on a link, it will show the doc file content in web page.

I am using PHP.

Comment: You need to explain your problem in a way that's possible to understand. What do you mean by "doc file", an MSWord file? What does your code look like? post code as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Content-Disposition` header, requesting it to be embedded:

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline');
```

This will hint the browser to show the file in the browser, but you cannot force it. If the browser does not support it, it'll prompt the download dialog anyway.